# jQuery AJAX functions return error 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)' even though the url exists

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form through AJAX to a .php file that will return either a true or false statement (eventually I will make this more complex but I am taking it one step at a time). Below is the code I am using:

```
  jQuery("#claimform").submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var $form = jQuery(this);
  var serializedData = $form.serialize();
  var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
  $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

  //alert("The serializedData is: " + serializedData);
  //http://www.wetcheck.com.au/wp-content/plugins/mobivate-sms/claim_check.php"+serializedData
  jQuery.get("http://www.wetcheck.com.au/wp-content/plugins/mobivate-sms/claim_check.php?"+serializedData, function(data){
    alert("Data: " + data);
});
```

However when I try to run this code I get the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) followed by the URL:

http://www.wetcheck.com.au/wp-content/plugins/mobivate-sms/claim_check.php?verification_c=423423&claim_id=7325&userid=90

The only problem is that the URL works! Yet no matter which ajax function I try (post/get/ajax) I always seem to come up with the same issue - that the server is responding with a status of 404 not found.

I have even tried to change

```
    jQuery.get("http://www.wetcheck.com.au/wp-content/plugins/mobivate-sms/claim_check.php?"+serializedData, function(data){
```

to

```
     jQuery.get("/wp-content/plugins/mobivate-sms/claim_check.php?"+serializedData, function(data){
```

and still it does not work.

Any input that anyone has for why this may be happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: Below is a screenshot of what I mean:

http://prntscr.com/iim1zm

Note that is the Web Inspector console in Safari. All the other browsers really slow down my Mac.

Oh and I am doing this in Wordpress if that helps.